# Why can't I open Facebook with a FB user's text from iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

When I open the iOS Facebook app with

```
fb://profile/44083897053
```

the app opens and goes to the proper page as expected.

When I use

```
fb://profile/philamuseum
```

the app opens, but I am taken to my timeline.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

The code being used is:

```
 @IBAction func gotoFacebook(_ sender: Any) {
    UIApplication.tryURL(urls:["fb://profile/\(self.facebookUser)/", "https://www.facebook.com/\(self.facebookUser)"])
}

. . . .

extension UIApplication {
class func tryURL(urls: [String]) {
    let application = UIApplication.shared
    for url in urls {
        if application.canOpenURL(URL(string: url)!) {
            application.open(URL(string: url)!)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked at number of questions re opening facebook from an iOS app here and elsewhere and have not found any recent answer that bears on this issue.

Comment: I would guess it happens because Facebook doesn't support `fb://profile/philamuseum`

Comment: Where is what Facebook does and does not support documented?

Comment: `fb:` links are not supported at all.